# Упрощение написания функции получения данных из mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно упростить это ужасную ф-ю.

```
function checkEventById($link, $event_id)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM events WHERE id = '$event_id' LIMIT 1");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($rows == 1) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Все дело в том, что если `$link` объявить как переменную вне ф-ии и не передавать ее как параметр в ф-ю, то выдает ошибку в запросе `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Обычно это решается через классы и переменные класса: Переменная $link будет один раз создана в конструкторе или передана туда как параметр, далее ее уже не надо передавать, достаточно обращаться как $this->link. Кстати, в этом запросе вы можете убрать LIMIT, ничего не изменится. А возвращать можно сразу return mysqli_num_rows($result) — он точно будет либо 1, либо 0.

Comment: @artoodetoo а можно пример с классом? спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: @lolbas да, ошибку выдает все равно.

Comment: какую ошибку? их много бывает. и `$link` объявлена до описания функции?

Comment: @lolbas ошибка, что данная переменная не может быть глобальной.

Comment: @wao138 ошибся, `global $link; $result = ...`

Comment: @lolbas не нужно учить плохим привычкам. Если можно обойтись без `global`, то лучше его не использовать

Comment: @AleksG например?